# VSCode adding line breaks between each line of a file, file opens fine in Sublime and VIM

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I pulled the project's main branch from Github and the differences showed extra lines added. When I opened the files in [VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnyjf.png) they had extra lines between each line of code.

I opened the file in [Sublime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSroy.png), VIM, using CAT and on [Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCv0f.png) and there are no extra lines.

However, if I remove the lines in VSC it shows as a change to the file and needs to be committed.

I couldn't find anything useful with Google but may have missed some obvious wording.

Does anyone know what's happening and how to fix it, please?

Tried resetting VSC settings to see if there was a bug, no dice.

Deleted local repo copy and pulled it fresh, no dice.

Pulled the theme directly from Shopify bypassing GH and the lines were present again so must be a VSC issue.

**Edit:** I [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXriT.png) one of the files using cat and the -A (all) flag and noticed that every line is appended with "^M^M$". I don't know where this has come from but that's got to be the cause.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to your newline settings. Those are carriage returns being shown.